# Yocto bitbake: exclude recipe dependency from native build only

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have an application A that depends on library B. But library B can only build for the target, i.e. non-native. Also, I need to build A for both the host and the target. Unfortunately, I get an error like this:
`Nothing PROVIDES B-native (but A-native DEPENDS or otherwise requires it)` 
In the recipe for A, I have tried numerous variations of

`DEPENDS_append = "B" DEPENDS_remove = "B-native" DEPENDS-${PN}-native_remove = "B-native"`

to no avail.
I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but I haven't found the correct combination of commands yet.